# Extraccion Datos

Tags: java, scraping

Muy buenas a todos y gracias de antemano.

Necesito recoger de varias paginas web la información de todos sus productos.

He probado a descargar con webcopy y hacer programas para recoger la información que necesito... pero algunas paginas son demasiado grandes y no las descarga enteras o la pagina esta protegida contra este tipo de actividades.

He mirado tutoriales de scraping... pero todos ellos están orientados a sacar información de una ruta única... y yo necesito extraer de un barbaridad de paginas de las cuales no dispongo de su url.

para que os hagáis una idea del volumen he generado 8.0000 jsp en total 40.000 productos pero esto no es mas que 1/4 si podéis orientarme de algún modo os estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigado, saludos.

Comment: Ha que te refieres con que no conoces su URL? supongo que a lo que te refieres es entrar a un X pagina y navegar en ella de ahi obtener esos productos  verdad?